# images loading after switching tabs in browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

Just to make everyone clear, tabs with double apostrophes "tabs" means the browser tabs and the one without apostrophes means jquery ui tabs. I have made a html page having two tabs namely gallery and grid using jquery ui. In one tab i.e the active tab(grid) I used fancy box plugin which is working fine and in the gallery tab I used flexslider plugin and this is where I am getting a strange issue.

When I click on the gallery tab no images are displayed just the border of the carousel and slider but when I switch browser "tabs" and come back to my page again the slider image gets displayed and when I do the switching again the slider images gets displayed. I don't know why is this happening and its bugging me off. Any help will be appreciated!!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="images/header_image.jpg" />   <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg"/></a>

            <div class="search">
                <button>
                    <img src="images/search_icon.jpg">
                </button>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--header-->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="menu_bar">   <a href="index.html"><li>About Us</li></a>
    <a href="my_pictures.html"><li class="active">My Pictures</li></a>
    <a href="my_music.html"><li>My Music</li></a>
    <a href="my_files.html"><li>My Files</li></a>
    <a href="my_videos.html"><li>My Videos</li></a>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--menu-->
        <div class="main_content">
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul class="my_pictures">
                    <li class="picture_menu"><a href="#tabs-1">Grid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="picture_menu"><a href="#tabs-2">Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1" class="grid_view"> <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic2.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic3.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic4.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic5.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic6.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/big_violin.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic8.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic9.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic9.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic10.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic11.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic11.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic12.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic12.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic13.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic13.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic14.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic14.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/pic15.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/pic15.jpg" alt="" /></a>

                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2" class="gallery_view">
                    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/gun.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/boombox.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/book.png">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic4.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic5.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic6.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/big_violin.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic8.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic9.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic10.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic11.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic12.jpg">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic1.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic2.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic3.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic5.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic6.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic7.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic8.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic9.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic10.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic11.jpg" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/pic12.jpg" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--main_content-->
        <div class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">EULA</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer_content">
                <img src="images/footer_image.jpg">copyright&copy;&nbsp;2012 My Website. All rights reserved.</div>
            <div class="social_icons">  <a href="https://blogger.com" target="blank"><img src="images/blogger.jpg"></a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="images/facebook.jpg"></a>
    <a href="https://digg.com" target="blank"><img src="images/digg.jpg"></a>
    <a href="https://linkedin.com" target="blank"><img src="images/in.jpg"></a>
    <a href="https://evernote.com" target="blank"><img src="images/evernote.jpg"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="blank"><img src="images/twitter.jpg"></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--footer-->
    </div>
    <!--main_container-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish_shetty/mer94nLe/)

Comment: When you switch to another browser tab, what is the url? Is it with id for second tab, for eg `www.example.com#tab-2`? Also you need to make the fiddle working than just paste the HTML CSS there.

Comment: no!! there is no url. just pressing the new tab button of the browser.and when i switch back to the html page, slider images get displayed.

Comment: Ok strange. Can you make the second tab active by default and check if it works properly? Also what you can do is rather than adding flexslider to the second tab content on load, add it on click of the tab-2 for the first time.

Comment: hey! I made the second tab active by default and its working properly. Images get displayed as soon as the i refresh the page but its not working when i make first tab active again!!

Comment: and the strange thing i noticed is that it is not just while switching browser tabs but the same thing happens when i switch between my open applications!!